# When a radio station plays a song but it doesn't show up in their 'recently played' list online, what does this mean?

Tags: pop, radio, media

I'm not sure if all radio stations do this, but a station I listen to has a page online where they list their 'recently played' songs. But I notice there are certain songs that don't show up. Furthermore, at least insofar as I've noticed the phenomenon, certain specific songs will never show up (rather than, say, the same one song being listed sometimes but not other times).